# .htaccess rewrite rule for structured modules

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working with a folder structure as follows:
Current URL:
http://test.com/modules/login/login.php?v=1&v2=2&v3=3

I am TRYING:
http://test.com/modules/login/login/v/1/v2/2/v3/3

My Root File starts after: http://test.com/

And I am trying to write .htaccess to hide the GET method values and .php file name from URL but due to more tree structured URL I am facing issues.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  login.php?$1=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  login.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  login.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [QSA,L]
```

The above method is not working?

Do we need to write Rules for individual file are it can be done in single rule??

I tried the following also:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ login.php?user=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ login.php?user=$1&page=$2
```

My Folder Structure:

```
----Myproject
-------Config
------------config.php
-------Includes
------------Images
-----------------image.jpg
------------CSS
-----------------test.css
------------JS
-----------------test.js
-------Modules
------------Home
-----------------index.php
------------settings
-----------------config.php
------------login
-----------------login.php
------------Contact 
------------MyPage
-------(.htaccess)
```

Comment: Question is still unclear. What URI you want to enter in browser? And what do you it to become internally?

Comment: Should URL not be: `http://test.com/modules/login/v/1/v2/2/v3/3` instead of `http://test.com/modules/login/login/v/1/v2/2/v3/3` with `/login/login` ?

Comment: Also like to know where your login.php is in your directory structure.

Comment: i have updated my question check out for directory.. @anubhava

Comment: OK thanks. So all php files are always 2 level deep after /modules/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(modules/[^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(modules/[^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

#### External Redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(modules/[^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(modules/[^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Sorry corrected, I was testing that rule on localhost using `/index.php` and got copy-pasted. But it also proves that rule was tested before posting :-)

Comment: :( nope it isnt working.. not changing in URL? what would be the reason??

Comment: i placed the htaccess inside my root. i have update it in my folder structure kindly check it.

Comment: I am on mobile now. Will check it once I am back on my computer in few minutes.

Comment: Did you enter this URI in browser: `http://test.com/modules/login/login/v/1/v2/2/v3/3`? Did it cause 404 or any other error? Is `MyProject/config` your DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: MyProject/DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: Example: MyProject/modules/settings/district/region_id/12/district_id/13/id/1/

Comment: Yes I got 404 Error!!

Comment: But you're entering this URLhttp://test.com/modules/login/login/v/1/v2/2/v3/3 in the browser?

Comment: I am testing these rules in my `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`. If I enter `/modules/login/login/v/1/v2/2/v3/3` in my browser it **correctly loads** `/modules/login/login.php?v3=3&v2=2&v=1` internally. What happens when you open: `http://test.com//modules/login/login.php?v3=3&v2=2&v=1`?

Comment: I am just calling the url using Menu/Navigation if the Rule is working it should change the URL Rite? but it is not working. :(

Comment: No rule is **not supposed to change the URL** If you want that add `R` flag. (see update in answer) Also navigate your page in Firebug and see which URL is causing 404 and then report back.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /give your full path of your project/
#for hidding get request
# Redirect /login?id=2 to /login/2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}^[A-Z]/+login\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login?%1 [R=302,L]
#for hidding .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: My Actual URL is like the below: http://localhost/svn/modules/settings/hello.php After http://localhost/svn/ the ROOT starts!!

Comment: @NeerajKumar `^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+` - What does that mean?

Comment: All alphabets form A - Z with 3 sized string

Comment: @NeerajKumar ...and then space symbol with mandatory one or more slash

Comment: it reads from the url request so till get request there will be multiple slashes to read till get request

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk I have changed the code thanks for making me understand the exact thing.

Comment: I think that space check `\s` is redundant isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Just what are you trying to do? What does the **incoming** URL (Search Engine Friendly/SEO?) look like, and what does it need to be converted to for your PHP file to work wityh it? Your problem specification is extremely hazy. Give some examples.

Comment: Are there a variable or fixed number of such parameter pairs? If variable, are there "reasonable" minimum and maximum counts of pairs? Why is "login" there twice? Could this be made more generic for /module/X/X.php?var=val&... ? (with just one "X" in the SEO URL). You're not "hiding" anything -- you're just making the public URI a little cleaner and aesthetically pleasing with this "SEO/SEF" format.